# Data Set to Tree Structure

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, tree

I have the below set of data

[image]

Where each City belongs to a specific Department, which belongs to a specific Region, which belongs to a specific Country (in this case there is only one country: France).

This data is contained in a CSV file which I can read from on a row-by-row basis, however my goal is to convert this data into a tree structure (with France being at the root).

Each of these nodes will be given a specific Id value, which is something I've already gone and done, but the tricky part is that each node here must also contain a ParentId (for instance Belley and Gex need the ParentId of Ain, but Moulins and Vichy need the ParentId of Aller).

Below is a snippet of code I've written that has assigned an Id value to each name in this data set, along with some other values:

```
int id = 0;
List<CoverageAreaLevel> coverageAreas = GetCoverageAreaDataFromCsv(path, true);
List<LevelList> levelLists = new List<LevelList>
{
    new LevelList { Names = coverageAreas.Select(a => a.Level1).Distinct().ToList(), Level = "1" },
    new LevelList { Names = coverageAreas.Select(a => a.Level2).Distinct().ToList(), Level = "2" },
    new LevelList { Names = coverageAreas.Select(a => a.Level3).Distinct().ToList(), Level = "3" },
    new LevelList { Names = coverageAreas.Select(a => a.Level4).Distinct().ToList(), Level = "4" }
};
List<CoverageArea> newCoverageAreas = new List<CoverageArea>();
foreach (LevelList levelList in levelLists)
{
    foreach (string name in levelList.Names)
    {
        CoverageArea coverageArea = new CoverageArea
        {
            Id = id++.ToString(),
            Description = name,
            FullDescription = name,
            Level = levelList.Level
        };
        newCoverageAreas.Add(coverageArea);
    }
}
```

The `levelLists` variable contains a sort-of heirarchical structure of the data that I'm looking for, but none of the items in that list are linked together by anything.

Any idea of how this could be implemented? I can manually figure out each ParentId, but I'd like to automate this process, especially if this needs to be done in the future.

Comment: This sounds like a database structure question, not a c# question.  To clarify what you're attempting to do, please edit your question and add in your code segment that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this problem yourself, and then explain at what point in that code you're not getting the results you expect.  This will help us better understand your approach and also provides more focus to your question.

Comment: @devlincarnate is not correct here at all and has jumped to some MASSIVE conclusions

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: asking for clarification is jumping to conclusions?  :D  and not just any conclusions...MASSIVE  ones.  8D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could solve this is by building dictionaries with the names and IDs of each level.

Assuming you have data like this:

```
var models = new List<Model> 
{
    new Model { Country = "France", Region = "FranceRegionA", Department = "FranceDept1", City = "FranceA" },
    new Model { Country = "France", Region = "FranceRegionA", Department = "FranceDept1", City = "FranceB" },
    new Model { Country = "France", Region = "FranceRegionA", Department = "FranceDept2", City = "FranceC" },
    new Model { Country = "France", Region = "FranceRegionB", Department = "FranceDept3", City = "FranceD" },
    new Model { Country = "Italy", Region = "ItalyRegionA", Department = "ItalyDept1", City = "ItalyA" },
    new Model { Country = "Italy", Region = "ItalyRegionA", Department = "ItalyDept2", City = "ItalyB" },
};
```

You could do something like this, which can probably be improved further if needed:

```
var countries = models.GroupBy(x => x.Country)
    .Select((x, index) => Tuple.Create(x.Key, new { Id = index + 1 }))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);

var regions = models.GroupBy(x => x.Region)
    .Select((x, index) => Tuple.Create(x.Key, new { ParentId = countries[x.First().Country].Id, Id = index + 1 }))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);

var departments = models.GroupBy(x => x.Department)
    .Select((x, index) => Tuple.Create(x.Key, new { ParentId = regions[x.First().Region].Id, Id = index + 1 }))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);

var cities = models
    .Select((x, index) => Tuple.Create(x.City, new { ParentId = departments[x.Department].Id, Id = index + 1 }))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);
```

The main idea is to leverage the `index` parameter of the `Select` method and the speed of dictionaries to find the parent ID.

Sample output [from a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CZwUYr):

```
countries:
   [France, { Id = 1 }],
   [Italy, { Id = 2 }]

regions:
   [FranceRegionA, { ParentId = 1, Id = 1 }],
   [FranceRegionB, { ParentId = 1, Id = 2 }],
   [ItalyRegionA, { ParentId = 2, Id = 3 }]

departments:
   [FranceDept1, { ParentId = 1, Id = 1 }],
   [FranceDept2, { ParentId = 1, Id = 2 }],
   [FranceDept3, { ParentId = 2, Id = 3 }],
   [ItalyDept1, { ParentId = 3, Id = 4 }],
   [ItalyDept2, { ParentId = 3, Id = 5 }]

cities:
   [FranceA, { ParentId = 1, Id = 1 }],
   [FranceB, { ParentId = 1, Id = 2 }],
   [FranceC, { ParentId = 2, Id = 3 }],
   [FranceD, { ParentId = 3, Id = 4 }],
   [ItalyA, { ParentId = 4, Id = 5 }],
   [ItalyB, { ParentId = 5, Id = 6 }]
```

Comment: Is there a way to assign `index` to a specific integer, and then iterate from there?

Comment: @Delfino What's the difference between that and `index + 1` in my sample above? :)

Comment: I suppose there is none, though when it comes to Lambda expressions my brain turns to mush :P

Comment: So, for example, how does each city know its specific ParentId, and avoid having all the cities just be assigned the same id?

Comment: @Delfino Each city has it's own parentId by the lookup done in `ParentId = departments[x.Department].Id` (so find the department with the given name in the dictionary and get its id)

Answer (score 4):

The solution from @Camilo is really good and pragmatic. I would also suggest the use of a tree.

A sample implementation:

```
var countries = models.GroupBy(xco => xco.Country)
        .Select((xco, index) =>
        {
            var country = new Tree<String>();
            country.Value = xco.Key;
            country.Children = xco.GroupBy(xr => xr.Region)
                    .Select((xr, xrIndex) =>
                    {
                        var region = new Tree<String>();
                        region.Value = xr.Key;
                        region.Parent = country;
                        region.Children =
                                xr.GroupBy(xd => xd.Department)
                                    .Select((xd, index) =>
                                    {
                                        var department = new Tree<String>();
                                        department.Value = xd.Key;
                                        department.Parent = region;
                                        department.Children = xd
                                        .Select(xc => new Tree<String> { Value = xc.City, Parent = department });
                                        return department;
                                    });

                        return region;
                    });
            return country;
        });

public class Tree<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<Tree<T>> Children;
    public T Value;
    public Tree<T> Parent;
}
```

Comment: I have the image of a tree in my head, and it makes so much sense, but putting thought to code is hard :P

Comment: Sonotori (indeed in japanese)

Comment: @Delfino I edited my previous answer with a sample code.